# How to access the electron app object within my angular controller

Tags: angularjs, electron

Question as title. For some reason require('electron') is undefined. However require other node modules works.

```
    var electron = require('electron');
    // Module to control application life.
    var app = electron.app;

    angular.module('YourApp', ['ngMaterial'])
      .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {


        $scope.exitApp = function() {
          console.log(app); // Undefined ..
          app.exit();
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [FAQ](https://github.com/atom/electron/blob/v0.36.7/docs/faq/electron-faq.md#requireelectronxxx-is-undefined) check that you didn't accidentally install the `electron` package via NPM (that is not the Electron you're looking for).